# max value of max.in.flight.requests.per.connection keeping order

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe

> max.in.flight.requests.per.connection - This controls how many message
> batches the producer will send to the server without receiving
> responses.

So, assuming we have max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5. We have enable.idempotence = true. Kafka guarantees ordering with max.in.flight.requests.per.connection <= 5. Kafka stores sequence numbers for each message. And we have the following situation with failing and recovering broker again and again:

1. message(batch of messages) with sequence number 1 is unlucky and always go to retry
2. other messages are being successfully committed again and again

Producer receive responses for all messages, hence, we don't overfill max.in.flight.requests.per.connection
Then the message with s.n. 1 is finally committed, and Kafka seems to guarantee the order(it will have the first offset), even if millions of messages have been committed before this first(assuming we have retry = infinity and huge time setting for retry).

Why 5 is the max value for max.in.flight.requests.per.connection then? Or why is the described situation unreal?

Comment: Does kafka watch on the delta of sequence numbers as well? E.g.: we committed a message with s.n.=1, but a message with s.q.=2 still isn't committed, hence a message with s.q.=6 won't be committed?